# How to flatten a calculation graph for a loop with accumulator(symbolic variables)?

Tags: python, theano

I'm a newbie in theano. But I've already googled,  read official theano documentation & 
I haven't found any clue how to solve my problem.

I'm trying to reinvent the wheel: I'm implementing my own batch convolution using theano.
(I'm doing so to learn this library)

So, here's what I'm trying to do:

```
# lr_all_w is a 3-tensor of <filter #, width, height>
lr_all_w = self._all_W.dimshuffle(('x', 0, 1)).repeat(self._prev_layer._processors_count, axis=0)

# element-wise to self._in_weight_masks
lr_all_w = lr_all_w * self._in_weight_masks
lr_all_w.name = 'lr_all_w'

#convolved = T.tensor3("convolved_batch")
# 'convolved' represents a dense convolved batches using im2col
convolved = T.zeros((self.batch_size, self._processors_count, self._processor_side**self._rec_f_dim))
convolved.name = "convolved_batches"

for batch_idx in range(self.batch_size):
    for i in range(self._prev_layer._processors_count):
        convolved = T.inc_subtensor(convolved[batch_idx], T.dot(lr_all_w[i], im2col_prev_layer[batch_idx, i]))

    # and adding bias
    convolved = T.inc_subtensor(convolved[batch_idx], self._all_B)
```

This results in a very deep calculation graph, because inc_subtensor is added on top of each previous operation:

inc_subtensor_stepN(inc_subtensor_stepN-1(inc_subtensor_stepN-2...

So I tried to flatten it. As all variables are symbolic, I realised, that I have to substitute them in some way in graph.

I tried theano.clone, but it results into the same situation as inc_subtensor.

Then I tried to use theano.scan:

```
sym_im2col_prev_layer_batch_idx = T.tensor3("sym_im2col_prev_layer_batch_idx")
#TODO replace sym_im2col_prev_layer_batch_idx with concrete substitution afterwards
result, updates = theano.scan( fn=lambda lr_all_w_i, im2col_prev_layer_batch_idx_i: T.dot(lr_all_w_i, im2col_prev_layer_batch_idx_i),
 sequences=[lr_all_w, sym_im2col_prev_layer_batch_idx])

to_substitute = result.sum(0)
to_substitute.name = 'to_substitute'

for batch_idx in range(self.batch_size):
    for i in range(self._prev_layer._processors_count):
        sym_im2col_prev_layer_curr_batch = theano.clone(
            to_substitute, {sym_im2col_prev_layer_batch_idx: im2col_prev_layer[batch_idx]}
        )
        convolved = T.set_subtensor(convolved[batch_idx], sym_im2col_prev_layer_curr_batch)

    # and adding bias
    convolved = T.set_subtensor(convolved[batch_idx], convolved[batch_idx] + self._all_B)
```

But still, I'm getting "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison"
right the first time when sym_im2col_prev_layer_curr_batch = theano.clone  is being executed.

The latter code snippet example shows right the thing I'm going to do. But I have no idea why I'm getting a 'maximum recursion depth exceeded'.
Because each time I do theano.clone, theano is supposed to substitute sym_im2col_prev_layer_batch_idx (which is already used in scan) with 
it's exact symbolic value - im2col_prev_layer[batch_idx], and give me a copy of this subgraph.
I might have missed something...

How such(or similar) tasks are solved in theano & how can I avoid too deep calculation graphs when
doing such tasks?

Also I tried such approach:

I've tried such approach:

```
for batch_idx in range(self.batch_size):
    result, updates = theano.scan(fn=lambda lr_all_w_i, im2col_prev_layer_batch_idx_i: T.dot(lr_all_w_i, im2col_prev_layer_batch_idx_i),
                                  sequences=[lr_all_w, im2col_prev_layer[batch_idx]])

    result = result.sum(0)
    convolved = T.set_subtensor(convolved[batch_idx], result)


    # and adding bias
    convolved = T.inc_subtensor(convolved[batch_idx], self._all_B)
```

But when trying to print the value of 'convolved' right after the 'for' cycle, I'm getting:

```
ipdb> theano.printing.debugprint(convolved)
...
*** RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

So, the same story.

Increasing recursion depth for python is NOT an option.

Any ideas how to flatten the calculation graph for my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general `theano.scan` is the solution for recursive situations. In a case like yours `theano.scan` should be used to *replace* a Python `for` loop, not in addition to the `for` loop.

It's difficult to see exactly what you're trying to achieve but the extensive use of `set_subtensor` and `inc_subtensor` suggests you're thinking about this in a way that is not well matched with how Theano wants to work. `theano.scan` might allow you to achieve what you want using the approach you're currently taking but, after a quick scan through the code you've provided, it doesn't look like even `theano.scan` is required. If one iteration does not rely on results from a previous iteration, as appears to be the case, then you can probably do this without any loops at all (neither Python `for` loops or a `theano.scan`) by judicious use of Theano tensor operations. The non-loop approach would almost certainly be far more efficient and speedy than doing things via a loop of some kind. Admittedly, these can be more difficult to wrap your head around than sequential, one-row-at-a-time type, operations.

If you can't see how your computation might be achieved via plain multi-dimensional tensor operations without loops then I would suggest looking into how you can replace your Python `for` loops with as few `theano.scan` operations as you can get away with.

Comment: Good points, +1, but the exercise mentioned in the OP probably already goes against how `Theano` wants to work ;) As far as I understand the (non executable) code above, it is written to emulate `T.nnet.conv2d` or something similar. So directly using the latter would be best practice.

Comment: After reading your comment, I've realised, that I have to shift my look at things in Theano.(it needs to be said, that I received the same response from you & in theano-users google group) So I realised that it's impossible to resolve this task using scan.

Sometimes realising that 'it's impossible to do this way' pushes you to look for other solutions. So I found this one:
<code>
convolved = T.tensordot(im2col_prev_layer, lr_all_w, ((1, 2), (0, 2)))
convolved = convolved.dimshuffle((0, 2, 1)) + self._all_B.dimshuffle(('x', 0, 1)).repeat(self.batch_size, axis=0)
</code>